# MooTools DOMReady not firing in IE7 if attached after DOM is ready through yepnope

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, mootools, domready, yepnope

I am using yepnope to load my scripts, but when using IE7, it won't fire the Mootools domready OR load events if they have already been fired. Any idea why?

Here is the code.

```
yepnope([
    {
        load: "/js/uncompressed/mootools.js",
        callback: function () {
            if (Browser.ie && Browser.version.toFloat() < 8) {
                yepnope([
                    {
                        load: "/js/uncompressed/ie.js",
                        complete: function () {
                            window.addEvent("domready", function () {
                                setupForIE();
                            });
                        }
                    }
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Using MooTools version 1.3.2 (no compat) and yepnope bundled with Modernizr.

After more testing, it seems that IE9 and IE8 aren't firing the domready either.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are loading Mootools "Asyncronously", maybe the js-Library loading after the `DOMContentLoaded` - event has already fired, thus your function not got executed.